# How to create a state diagram in doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen

Using doxygen I would like to produce state diagrams somehow. Are there any tricks in doxygen to help us achieve that?

Currently I am just using the pre-formatted text and then adding my own "free-text-diagram" which is hard to maintain and time-consuming to draw out.

I use all of the other diagrams produced by doxygen (i.e. inheritance, relations, etc...) but since state machines are not a "standard" c/c++ construct (i.e. eech designer can implemente them differently) I guess there is no automatic way to tell doxygen to do this for you. But is there some sort of creation of diagram elements that you can comment in next to each state?
Maybe somthing like this crude example:

```
\section state Diagram
... description

\state state1...
\value1 returns state2
\value2 returns state1
int myState1Handler(){...}

\state state2...
\value1 returns state1
\value2 returns state2
int myState2Handler(){...}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Or, is it possible to use the graphviz markup language as suggested in the comments below and integrate them with the doxygen output somehow?

Comment: Maybe there are possibilities to control graphviz output directly from some extra source somehow.

Comment: @g-makulik sounds complicated :o, but I will take a look around regarding graphviz thanks.

Comment: @g-makulik wow, actually graphviz looks really easy to produce state diagrams (and other such diagrams). But I have no idea how to insert some graphviz markup code into my code files and then get that into doxygen output... I guess that is what you meant by "control graphviz output"... [link to useful graphviz example](http://steveliles.github.io/making_pretty_diagrams_with_graphviz.html)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I know that doxygen uses graphviz internally to create the structural diagrams. I don't know if doxygen somehow exposes this interface to use it directly.

Comment: @g-makulik ah ok, damn :) I will add that as part of the question and also look into it, thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at the \dot and \dotfile commands of doxygen

Comment: THX @albert you beat me to the answer ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doxygen (at least the latest version) provides the [`\dotfile`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddotfile) and [`\dot`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddot) special commands to insert arbitrary .dot files or inline dot graph descriptions to be rendered with graphviz to the generated documentation.

You might also consider to manage your state machines (by modelling, visual representation and code generation) using a tool like e.g. [SMC](http://smc.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll give this a go! SMC looks awesome too :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add your own custom graphs within doxygen using the dot script language and by putting the script between `\dot` and `\enddot`

I tested this example myself in my cpp code and it works great with doxygen:

```
/*! 
   Class relations expressed via an inline dot graph:
   \dot
   digraph example {
       node [shape=record, fontname=Helvetica, fontsize=10];
       b [ label="class B" URL="\ref B"];
       c [ label="class C" URL="\ref C"];
       b -> c [ arrowhead="open", style="dashed" ];
   }
   \enddot
   Note that the classes in the above graph are clickable
   (in the HTML output).
 */

void main()
{
  //write some code here...
}
```

result:

[image: doxygen output with your own custom dot graph]

To see more examples of dot graph scripts see the following sources:

1. https://edotor.net/ - this actually shows you examples and you can change them and see the result immediately on the right.
2. http://msc-generator.sourceforge.net/help/5.4/Graph-Language-Tutorial.html - nice examples
3. https://graphviz.org/documentation/ -  total documentation of dot language for those who want to go deep.

Comment: The above links are really nice, thanks. Are you the author of the msc-generator? In the second link, I see the left dot code is in image format, I would suggest change it to text format, so we can simply copy and paste.

Comment: @ollydbg23 I am not the author of msc-generator. But I agree with your recommendation :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add plantuml to this question. This is a text-based uml diagram generator. The great thing about it is that you can generate run-time outputs (state diagrams, sequence diagrams, etc...).

For example, each time you state-transition you print a plantuml formatted line to a file. When the programs terminates (or at any time really) you run the plantuml on the output file (may need to add start/end tags - trivial) and you get a uml diagram!... I have since used this on 3 different projects - mostly for sequence diagrams.

Ok so this is not really "offline" design-documentation, in some ways its better because you get self-documenting code in that the diagrams generated are exactly what the code is doing. Here is a very simple example of plantuml sequence diagram:

```
@startuml
component1 -> component2 : helloMsg
component2 -> component1 : replyMsg
@enduml
```

If that is the output from your program, then:

```
java -jar <path-to-plantuml.jar>/plantuml.jar myoutput.log
```

This generates: myoutput.png (image). Where plantuml.jar is a free download from plantuml website... free and simple!

Comment: Doxygen supports plantuml commands as written in this answer and will convert it, automatically, to an image. See the doxygen documentation (paragraphs about startuml and the  parts about the configuration option PLANTUML_....

Comment: @Caleth I know - I was the OP ... but that tool was really useful for me

Comment: @albert - oh cool! - even better, I did not know that Doxygen supports plantuml : )

Comment: @Caleth also this is not a java example - this is also for c++ or any language that can produce an file-based output (i.e. a log file). Plantuml uses java to process the output text file into a uml diagram.